# Pyspark - Avoid using explode

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, explode

I want to check a value of array column if is equal "A" without using "explode" or "UDF" because it make my DataFrame very Big and the process very slow.

so i have this

```
+-----+----+--------------------+---------+
| Name| Age|            Subjects|   Grades|
+-----+----+--------------------+---------+
|[Bob]|[16]|[Maths, Physics, ...|[A, B, C]|
+-----+----+--------------------+---------+
```

I want this

```
+-----+----+--------------------+---------+--------------------+
| Name| Age|            Subjects|   Grades|         test       |
+-----+----+--------------------+---------+--------------------+
|[Bob]|[16]|[Maths, Physics, ...|[A, B, C]|[true, false, false]|
+-----+----+--------------------+---------+--------------------+
```

Any Solution ?

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL `TRANSFORM` for that

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn("test", F.expr("TRANSFORM(Grades, x -> x = 'A')"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , you think that it is the fastest solution when you have aroud 200 columns (with <struct> and array field ) and millions of rows ?

Comment: I don't know if this is the fastest, but I think it is better than using explode and grouping them again from the perspective of memory usage

Comment: Thank you for you answer , yes explode ctrate billions rows in the output . So you i will try this or UDF last choice